# Why is my content_item div not loading html page through jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to rewrite a web template my friend wants for his new webpage.

It is using totally new pages for every menu option, which in my opinion is pretty ugly, so i wanted to make every menu button load a new transparent html page inside a div build for content, but for some reason it shows up blank without content and doesn't load the html i connected to the home button.

```css
html
{ height: 100%;}

*
{ margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}

body
{ font: normal 85% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #00BFFF url(../images/background.jpg) repeat;
  color: #000;
}

p
{ padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  font-size: 100% }

img
{ border: 0;}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 
{ font: normal 175% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #1D1D1D;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;}

h2
{ font: normal 165% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

h3
{ font: normal 130% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h4, h5, h6
{ margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0px 0;
  font: normal 150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;}

h5, h6
{ font: normal 95% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #888;
  padding-bottom: 15px;}

a
{ color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;}

a:hover
{ text-decoration: none;}

ul
{ margin: 2px 0 22px 30px;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 100%;}

ol
{ margin: 8px 0 22px 20px;}

ol li
{ margin: 0 0 11px 0;}

#main, #header, #banner, #menubar, #site_content, #footer, #content_bottom
{ margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;}

#main
{ background: transparent;}
  
#header
{ width: 960px;
  height: 120px;
  background: transparent;}

#banner
{ width: 960px;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 0 0 0;
  background: transparent;}

#menubar
{ width: 960px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #0043A8;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  } 
  
#welcome
{ width: 960px;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: transparent;} 
  
#welcome_slogan
{ width: 960px;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: transparent;}   
   
#welcome H1
{ font: normal 300% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -3px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #1D1D1D;}

#welcome_slogan H1
{ font: normal 200% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #1D1D1D;}  
  
ul#menu
{ margin:0;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;}

ul#menu li
{ padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  display: inline;
  background: transparent;}

ul#menu li a
{ float: left;
  font: bold 120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 24px;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #000;
  padding: 16px 20px 10px 20px;
  background: transparent; } 
  
ul#menu li.current a
{ color: #FFF;
  background: #323232;
  text-shadow: none;}
  
ul#menu li:hover a
{ color: #FFF;
  background: #323232;
  text-shadow: none;}

#site_content
{ width: 940px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #323232;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-border: 0px 0px 15px 15px;} 

.sidebar_container
{ float: left;
  margin: 10px 20px 0 0;
  width: 215px;
  padding: 0;}

.sidebar
{ float: left;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;}

.sidebar_item
{ font: normal 100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 215px;}

.sidebar h2
{ padding: 5px 0 0 10px;
  font: normal 140% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 30px;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #000;
  color: #fff;
  background: #0043A8;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-border: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;}  

#content
{ width: 680px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;}

.content_item
{ width: 680px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;}
  
.content_image
{ float: left; 
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;}
  
.content_container
{ width: 320px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;}
  
#content_bottom
 { width: 960px;
  height: 160px;
  text-align: center;} 
  
#content_bottom p
 { color: #000;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #FFF; }  

#content_bottom h4
{ color: #000;
  text-shadow: none;}
  
.content_bottom_container_box
{ width: 295px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 10px 10px;
  float: left;}

.content_bottom_container_boxl
{ width: 295px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 10px 10px;
  float: left;}
  
#footer
{ width: 960px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center; 
  background: transparent;
  color: #1D1D1D;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #FFF;}

#footer a, #footer a:hover
{ color: #1D1D1D;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 20px;}

#footer a:hover
{ text-decoration: underline;}
  
 .readmore
{ font: bold 110% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 15px;
  margin-left: 95px;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 5px 5px 10px 7px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-border: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;}
  
 .readmore a
{ color: #1D1D1D;}
 
 .button_small
{ font: normal 110% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 15px;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 5px 5px 10px 7px;
  background: #0043A8;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-border: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;}
  
.button_small a
{ color: #FFF;
  padding-left: 5px;}

.form_settings
{ margin: 15px 0 0 0;}

.form_settings p
{ padding: 0 0 4px 0;}

.form_settings span
{ float: left; 
  width: 280px; 
  text-align: left;}
  
.form_settings input, .form_settings textarea
{ padding: 2px; 
  width: 299px; 
  font: 100% arial; 
  border: 1px solid #E5E5DB; 
  background: #FFF; 
  color: #47433F;}
  
.form_settings input[type="checkbox"]
{ padding: 2px 0; 
  width: 15px; 
  font: 100% arial; 
  border: 0; 
  background: #FFF; 
  color: #47433F;
  margin: 28px 0;}

.form_settings .submit
{ font: 100% arial; 
  width: 99px; 
  margin: 0 0 0 206px; 
  height: 26px;
  padding: 2px 0 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer; 
  background: #0043A8;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#43A9FF, #0043A8);
  border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -webkit-border: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  color: #FFF;}

.slideshow {
  width: 680px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;}
  
/* styling for the slideshow on the homepage */
ul.slideshow {
  list-style: none;
  width: 680px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;}
  
ul.slideshow li {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;}
 
ul.slideshow li.show {
  z-index: 500;}
 
ul img {
  border: none;}
 
#slideshow-caption {
  width: 680px;
  height: 38px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; 
  z-index: 500;}
 
#slideshow-caption .slideshow-caption-container {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; 
  background: transparent url(../images/transparent.png) repeat;  
  z-index: 1000;}
 
#slideshow-caption p {
  padding: 0;
  font: normal 130% arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
  <title>ARaynorDesign Template</title>
  <meta name="description" content="free website template" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="enter your keywords here" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/image_slide.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    $(function() { // shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#content_item").load("main.html");
    });
</script>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="header">
   <div id="banner">
     <div id="welcome">
       <h1>Blue Skies</h1>
     </div><!--close welcome-->
     <div id="welcome_slogan">
       <h1>Your Company Slogan Here</h1>
     </div><!--close welcome_slogan-->
   </div><!--close banner-->
    </div><!--close header-->

 <div id="menubar">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li class="current"><a href="#" onclick='$("#content_item").load("main.html");'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick='$("#content_item").load("ourwork.html");'>Our Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick='$("#content_item").load("testimonials.html");'>Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick='$("#content_item").load("projects.html");'>Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick='$("#content_item").load("contact.html");'>Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--close menubar--> 
    
 <div id="site_content">  

   <div class="sidebar_container">       
  <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar_item">
            <h2>Nieuws</h2>
            <p>Welcome to our new website. Please have a look around, any feedback is much appreciated.</p>
          </div><!--close sidebar_item--> 
        </div><!--close sidebar-->       
  <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar_item">
            <h2>Latest Update</h2>
            <h3>March 2013</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus tempor enim.</p>         
    </div><!--close sidebar_item--> 
        </div><!--close sidebar-->
  <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar_item">
            <h3>February 2013</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus tempor enim.</p>         
    </div><!--close sidebar_item--> 
        </div><!--close sidebar-->  
  <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar_item">
            <h3>January 2013</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus tempor enim.</p>         
    </div><!--close sidebar_item--> 
        </div><!--close sidebar-->    
        <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar_item">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <p>Phone: +44 (0)1234 567891</p>
            <p>Email: <a href="mailto:info@youremail.co.uk">info@youremail.co.uk</a></p>
          </div><!--close sidebar_item--> 
        </div><!--close sidebar-->
       </div><!--close sidebar_container--> 
 
   <div class="slideshow">
     <ul class="slideshow">
          <li class="show"><img width="680" height="250" src="images/home_1.jpg" alt="&quot;Enter your caption here&quot;" /></li>
          <li><img width="680" height="250" src="images/home_2.jpg" alt="&quot;Enter your caption here&quot;" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>     
  
   <div id="content">
        <div class="content_item">  
  </div><!--close content_item-->
      </div><!--close content-->   
 </div><!--close site_content--> 
    
 <div id="content_bottom">
   <div class="content_bottom_container_box">
  <h4>Latest Blog Post</h4>
     <p> Phasellus laoreet feugiat risus. Ut tincidunt, ante vel fermentum iaculis.</p>
  <div class="readmore">
    <a href="#">Read more</a>
  </div><!--close readmore-->
   </div><!--close content_bottom_container_box-->
      <div class="content_bottom_container_box">
       <h4>Latest News</h4>
     <p> Phasellus laoreet feugiat risus. Ut tincidunt, ante vel fermentum iaculis.</p>
     <div class="readmore">
    <a href="#">Read more</a>
  </div><!--close readmore-->
   </div><!--close content_bottom_container_box-->
      <div class="content_bottom_container_boxl">
  <h4>Latest Projects</h4>
     <p> Phasellus laoreet feugiat risus. Ut tincidunt, ante vel fermentum iaculis.</p>
     <div class="readmore">
    <a href="#">Read more</a>
  </div><!--close readmore-->   
   </div><!--close content_bottom_container_box1-->      
   <br style="clear:both"/>
    </div><!--close content_bottom-->   
 
  </div><!--close main-->
  
  <div id="footer">
   <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">Valid XHTML</a> | <a href="http://fotogrph.com/">Images</a> | <a href="http://www.heartinternet.co.uk/vps/">Virtual Server</a> | website template by <a href="http://www.araynordesign.co.uk">ARaynorDesign</a>
  </div><!--close footer-->  
  
</body>
```

I've added the css part for the content div and the code i'm using, hopefully you guys can find the problem, cause i can't seem to find out why this is not working...

edit: I've added the whole code so it is easier to help me with this...

Comment: Did you load jquery library before your code?

Comment: Its giving a jquery error, you should load jquery in your html file.

Comment: i do load jquery in <head>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function load_home() {
   document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="main.html" ></object>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by loading jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Remove the *onclick* event from the *li* element like that

```
<div id="menubar">
   <ul id="menu">
       <li class="current"><a href ="#">Home</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Then add a click event when document loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".current").click(function(){
        $("#content").load("yourDocument.html");
    });
});
```

**Note**

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests (http://api.jquery.com/load/) are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.

Comment: i tried this but no effect, still an empty document :/ I do load the jquery inside the <head>. And i do have more menu options, so i think this options isn't what i was looking for as the click would always open main.html instead of depending on the menu button i press...

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: i am just stating a possible reason as to why your stuff is not working i am not recommending you do it this way.

In your html, you only have an onclick for the first menu item... are u not wanting this....

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="current">
        <a href="#" onclick='$("#content_item").load("main.html");'>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick='$("#content_item").load("ourwork.html");'>Our Work</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick='$("#content_item").load("testimonials.html");'>Testimonials</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick='$("#content_item").load("projects.html");'>Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick='$("#content_item").load("contact.html");'>Contact Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that is correct, i was trying to implement the onclick to open in the div, but as it isn't working i didn't even tried to edit the other buttons. still in progress of trying to get the template the way my friend wants it to be, so just basic stuff at the moment instead of content or stuff like doing all the buttons :)

Comment: the href should all be # ill update the thing, ps still not saything this is how it should be done...

Comment: still weird that this worked on another page i made, but doesn't on this one... :/

Comment: try give the full URL instead of a relative one. http:localhost\something.html, also see http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

According to your html code,"**content_item**" is a class name.In your code you are refereing this div as Id.

Instead of this

```
 onclick='$("#content_item").load("ourwork.html");
```

Use

```
 onclick='$(".content_item").load("ourwork.html");
```

In jquery, To access element by Id use prefix **#** and for class use **.(Dot)**

Comment: oh thx, didn't even notice that, but still no luck, even when i changed the id to class it still won't load the content of main.html.